# SDK 2.0p3 grid: showing hidden columns

Tags: sdk, extjs4, rally

Prior to 2.0p3 the user could choose to show hidden columns.

Is that still possible in 2.0p3?  It does not appear to be, but is there an option to enable this?  This functionality was nice in the previous versions, so I'm hoping it's not gone permanently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about hiding and showing columns in the context of a grid.

When you are adding in your grid configuration, you must add the following config:

```
gridConfig: {
    disableColumnMenus: false,
    // more config options go here...
}
```

That will reenable ExtJS's default of showing the drop down menu on each grid column.

In SDK 2.0p3, we disabled the column drop down header by default due to a combination of inconsistent functionality and minor styling issues. I just filed a defect regarding this issue to make the column chooser more consistent with the rest of the app (such as the Backlog page).

Comment: Since I am using this.add with the rallygrid xtype, I don't need a gridConfig object, but rather put disableColumnMenus: false right into the parameters, but yes-- that's what I needed, thanks!